How to seal shower pan / gasket / cast iron pipe
My shower pan appears to be leaking somewhere between the black rubber gasket, the cast iron pipe and the pastic bezel in the attached image.  I checked the gasket under the pan and the seal with the bezel itself and the larger gaskets underneath seems to be fine.
What is the proper / best way to seal this assembly?  I was thinking of just slathering the visible portion with silicone but I'd like some input to see if there is a better option or other considerations.


from the underside,  loosen the big clamping nut, pus the drain up. Put some plumbers putty between the drain flange and the shower base.  Tighten the nut back and clean off the excessive putty. This may take a friend to help.

@RMDman - I believe the joint between the flange and the base  is sealed so I'm not sure how this will help.  The leak appears to be coming between the cast iron and the rubber gasket.

@grue, then you know what to fix.

@RMDman - possibly but as I've never assembled one of these I don't quite understand the mechanics of that rubber flange around the cast iron or how it's supposed to be sealed.  With a toilet there is plenty of wax that makes that seal.  I've never done a shower drain or seen one of these gaskets before.

As we can see in your photo, your drain is an E.L Mustee 42.317.   It uses flat washers and a nut to seal itself above and below the shower floor, but the seal to the drain pipe is formed by a rubber sleeve that is ribbed inside and outside. The pipe is not joined to the drain by a nut or a flange, it just slips inside the rubber sleeve.
This is the product, this (page 2) is how you install it.  There are some videos on the Mustee web site.
The exact drain with all new washers and sleeve can be purchased easily.  It's not expensive.  Rather than figure out what's wrong with yours, you should just replace the whole thing.  It's possible it was installed incorrectly, you can't tell and if you are going to take it all apart you should not reuse it.
If the iron pipe is so corroded that the rubber sleeve can't form a good seal, you should replace that while you are at it.  And if you replace it, you could use an identical one or go with a more standard drain kit, if one will fit your shower floor.

Thank you again.  The first answer, though incorrect for my case, was still informative.  The explanation here makes a lot of sense.  As I mentioned above, I ended up loosening everything and getting a bit of 100% silicone in between the drain and the base as well as in and around the entire cast iron pipe and the ribbed sleeve.  Though it may be a somewhat temporary fix, at the moment this is now leak free. Down the road, I will definitely be replacing with something more modern. I really appreciate the answer and the time you put in to correcting the other one!
